# Finding Link-Local IP in ifconfig (Linux - Redhat 9)

Tags: embedded, mips, ipv6, ifconfig, link-local

I set IPv6 in MIPS Embedded device.  I use 2.6.23 kernel and I set IPv6 items in menuconfig.  I updated kernel in the device but, link-local IP doesn't show in ipconfig as below:

**-> inet6 addr: /64 Scope:Link**

[image: terminal]

How can I set link-local IP?

I can find ipv6 address as below, but ifconfig is not...

[root@]# cat /proc/net/if_inet6

00000000000000000000000000000001 01 80 10 80       lo

fe8000000000000002032efffe070001 02 40 20 80     eth0

What is the problem? kernel? ifconfig (busybox-1.1.0)? anything else? Please give me any idea!~ Thank you~

Comment: Which os are you using?

Comment: If you don't have a link-local address then maybe the ipv6 kernel module isn't loaded

Comment: I compiled the 2.6.23 kernel in Linux (Redhat 9) flatform for MIPS embedded device. when I compiled, I used menuconfig. And I set 'built-in' IPv6 items in menuconfig.

Comment: Then, do I have to double check the IPv6 items in menuconfig?

Comment: Actually, I did double check the IPv6 items in the menuconfig

Comment: I'm not sure how much help anyone can be with a buggy, 10 year old kernel. Why aren't you using something less ancient?